# Passing variables to different classes

Tags: java, class, variables

I'm sure there is an extremely simple solution for this but I'm desperately struggling to find the answer. I'm trying to set the value from a main class into classA then retrieve that value in classB and do something else with it before returning the answer in the Main:

Example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        ClassA classA = new ClassA();
        ClassB classB = new ClassB();

        System.out.println("Number: ");
        classA.setX(input.nextInt());

        System.out.println("Total: " + classB.printTotal());

    } // main
} // class
```

Class A:

```
public class ClassA {
    int x;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
} // class
```

ClassB:

```
public class ClassB {
    ClassA classA;

    public int printTotal() {
        int y = classA.getX() * 5;
        return y;
    }
} // class
```

Whatever I input returns null. I understand why this is the case but I don't know the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ClassB` should define the dependency on `ClassA` either through constructor or a (setter) method:

```
public ClassB(ClassA classA) {
    this.classA = classA;
}

//or/and

public void setClassA(ClassA classA) {
    this.classA = classA;
}
```

And inject the dependency in `main` as follows:

```
ClassB classB = new ClassB(classA);
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having an instance of ClassA in ClassB, perhaps you should pass in a ClassA object as a parameter to printTotal:

```
public class ClassB {
    public int printTotal(ClassA classA) {
        int y = classA.getX() * 5;
        return y;
    }
} // class
...

System.out.println("Total: " + classB.printTotal(classA));
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for providing another answer that also solved my question.

Answer (score 1):

**In main, set classA variable of classB with classA object, rest should be fine.**

If your both the classes are in the **same package**, then you can simply assign the object as below and you are done.

```
    ClassA classA = new ClassA();
    ClassB classB = new ClassB();
    classB.classA = classA;//assign classA to ClassB's classA attribute
```

---

**otherwise:**

```
    ClassA classA = new ClassA();
    ClassB classB = new ClassB();
    classB.setClassA(classA);//assign classA to ClassB's classA attribute
```

and in ClassB, add a setter method as:

```
     public void setClassA(ClassA classA){
        this.classA = classA;
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear example, and answer. I now have 3 ways to implement a solution and this additional solution helped me fully understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your ClassB has no reference to an instance of ClassA. So you can use again a setter or maybe better set the instance of ClassA with the constructor:

```
public ClassB(ClassA instance) {
   this.classA = instance;
}
```

Comment: and ideally, it has not just any reference, but one to the instance that you set your X on.

Comment: Insert I missed that wo write because it is so oblivious. Maybe he want to use zero? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In `class B`, `classA` should refer to an object of `A`.

Include a constructor in `class B`

```
public B(A a) {
    this.classA = a;
}
```

In the main method, initialize `classB` with `classB = new B(classA);`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add to ur main before printing the value.

```
 classB.classA = classA;
```

so the classA initialized in your classb can have the x value you set in your main.
Hope this helps good luck!